# How to remove rows containing character in Pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas data frame, and I would like to remove all rows where there is a character "?" in column 6.
Assuming df is my data frame, I tried:

```
df2 = df[df[6].str.contains("\?")==False]
```

This, however, does only seem to generate a view of my original frame (when I print df2, the rows I wanted to remove are gone, but the row indices skip values at the removed rows...).
How can I obtain an independent new data frame df2 where the targeted rows are gone?

edit: the frame looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do that:

```
df2 = df[~df[6].str.contains("?")].reset_index(drop=True)
df2
```

Comment: This gives an error: "error: nothing to repeat"

Comment: Pls post a sample of your dataframe